# Opening files in another computer c#

Tags: c#, audio, path

I have a program that a button, when clicked, executes a sound located in my download folder. My question is how to execute the sound on another computer if the path for finding it is different.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean make the other computer play the sound or your computer make play a sound file on the other computer??

Answer (score 1):

You need the path to a file to run it. If you don't have the path - you have to search for it.

1. Pick a base directory where you think the file is. If you don't know where - that will be the whole drive.
2. Write a recursive function that would search said folder recursively.
3. Test each file by what ever your search condition is, i.e. file name, file hash, etc.

For example:

```
string SearchForFile(string searchPath, Func<string, bool> searchPredicate)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchPath))
        {
            if (searchPredicate(fileName))
            {
                return fileName;
            }
        }

        foreach (string dirName in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(searchPath))
        {
            var childResult = SearchForFile(dirName, searchPredicate);
            if (childResult != null)
            {
                return childResult;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var filePath = SearchForFile(@"C:\", x => Path.GetFileName(x) == "yourFileName.mp3");
```